# How to assign the Expire date for AccessToken in QuickBooks

Tags: .net, quickbooks-online

I am creating a .Net application to connect with Quickbooks Online. I am unable to assign the AccessToken duration time without using OAuthPlayground

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't.

The Intuit-assigned duration of OAuth tokens is 180 days. There is no way to change this (nor any reason to change this either).

Comment: I tried to set the OAuth Token Expiration duration time to 180days in Playground.. but am unable to set the time .. when i change the OAuthDuration time it automatically revoke to 120Seconds by Default.. How can i set the Duration Time?

Comment: Why do you want to set the time? There should be no reason to set the expiration time...